# kendo ui angular2 charts hide dots for data points (in line mode)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo UI Chart with Angular 2, with the type of chart set to "Line".
This is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpNNkJTXGuhaHEhA4TvT?p=preview) with example from telerik documentation.
The question is: how to make a smooth line without the data points "dots"?

`<kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
    <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
            type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `markers="visible: false"` to the sries configuration, like this:

```
<kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
    <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series" markers="visible: false"
                    type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```